# Set the same image for UICollectionViewCell and UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

am getting color from my image with this extension

```
 extension UIImage {
func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

    let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}  
}
```

and am setting this in `cellForItemAt indexPath:`

```
  let img = cell.movieImage.image?.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
  cell.backgroundColor = img
  view.backgroundColor = img
```

but the `backgroundColor`of the `cell` does not match the `view`'s `backgroundColor`

EDIT: Added demo image

https://s30.postimg.org/gshw3u829/demo.gif

Comment: There is different types of colors like RGB, CYMK, etc, So, it happen that your color type is different among so it didnt match color. Check the color type of return from image and your cells background image. If its not the problem then match the RGB values of both image

Comment: The color is getting applied the color type is ok but the color on `view.backgroundColor` is different from  the cell color `cell.backgroundColor = img`

Comment: did you have your demo ? If you could send me to my mail or give me link of dropbox from where i can download and check

Comment: I edited the question there's a demo now

Comment: Can you send me demo at jiten.benzatine@gmail.com, So I can see your issue ?

Comment: I told you to send demo of coding not the gif image. send me xcode project please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting background Color of tableCell, try setting color of contentView

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = img
```

Comment: I think that wouldn't creating issue like you can directly set background color of cell

Comment: color of contentView overrides backgroundColor of cell, and all the views are. added on contentView

Comment: There's a demo..the cell background color doesn't match the view background when scrolling